# Set the frame of scene to be size of the iPhone screen

Tags: iphone, swift, ios8, sprite-kit

Hi I am new to sprite kit and for some reason when using self.frame.size.width or .height to position buttons or subviews in the scene they are not centered but rather sometimes show up completely off screen. Does anyone know how to set the frame size to be the size of the iphone/ipad im using?

here is my code when presenting a subview when player loses

```
func presentGameOverView() {

    if firstTime == true {
        let gameOverView = UIView()
        gameOverView.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width / 2.0, self.frame.size.height / 2.0, 200, 200) //should be center of screen
        gameOverView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        playGameOverSound()
        self.view?.addSubview(gameOverView)
        firstTime = false
    }
}
```

here is part of the gameViewController.swift

```
extension SKNode {
class func unarchiveFromFile(file : NSString) -> SKNode? {
    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file, ofType: "sks") {
        var sceneData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)!
        var archiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: sceneData)

        archiver.setClass(self.classForKeyedUnarchiver(), forClassName: "SKScene")
        let scene = archiver.decodeObjectForKey(NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as GameScene
        archiver.finishDecoding()
        return scene
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

}

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill


        //display banner Ads
        //self.canDisplayBannerAds = true

        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `width` and `height` are the dimensions of the `UIView` then the origin ,for the view to be at the centre, will be at point

```
 origin = (self.frame.size.width/2 - width/2, self.frame.size.height/2 - height/2)
```

So the `gameOverView` frame should be

```
let width : CGFloat = 200.0
let height : CGFloat = 200.0
gameOverView.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width/2 - width/2
    , self.frame.size.height/2 - height/2, width, height)
```

To not use the sks file, in `GameViewController` `viewDidLoad`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let scene = GameScene(size:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height))

    let skView = self.view as SKView
    skView.showsFPS = true
    skView.showsNodeCount = true

    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill


    skView.presentScene(scene)
}
```

You can also just extract the frame of the underlying `SKView` instead of the `frame` of the `scene`, and do this

```
if let viewFrame = self.view?.frame {
    let width : CGFloat = 200.0
    let height : CGFloat = 200.0
    gameOverView.frame = CGRectMake(viewFrame.size.width/2 - width/2
        , viewFrame.size.height/2 - height/2, width, height)
}
```

Comment: yea but for some reason that is not appearing in the gamescene. I dont know why but the frame is much larger than the screen size ive never had this happen before when I 
println(self.frame.size.width)
println(self.frame.size.height)
I get 1024, and 768

Comment: are you using an sks file?

Comment: when i created a sprite scene GameScene.sks was in the project folders...but all my code is in GameScene.swift

Comment: but I think the sks file will be loaded inside the GameViewController when you initialise the GameScene in viewDidLoad. please check and confirm

Comment: I added the gameviewcontroller code to the original question so you can take a look at the reference to sks

Comment: `scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene` this line reads the GameScene from the sks file

Comment: when i want to skip the sks file, i usually do, `let scene = GameScene(size:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height))` instead of that line

Comment: I get "Bound value in a conitional binding must be of optional type" when trying to replace that line of code @rakeshbs

Comment: check my updated code. you should replace the if statement too